Two brothers at lake, one becomes paralyzed by jumping off a bridge
All I can remember is there are two brothers, who are kids, and maybe a few friends. They are jumping in to a lake/river and the younger brother is afraid to jump. His older brother persuaded him to jump but just as he jumps a log/tree trunk floats under the bridge and the boy lands on it on his neck and becomes paralyzed. After a while, the older brother breaks down and admits that it was him that persuaded his brother to jump so he feels that it's his fault he is paralyzed. 
Does anyone know the name of this film?

You're after the film A Step Toward Tomorrow from 1996 with Judith Light and Christopher Reeve. From an online synopsis:

A young boy is paralysed from the waist down after diving from a bridge and hitting a log that no one had seen. His brother feels guilty because he egged his brother on and is very protective about him. Their mother is divorced and decides to move from Idaho to Georgia because she has heard of a good neurosurgeon. 

Here's the promo:




Thanks a lot, I thought I'd never find out the title of this

@StevenBradford No problem. Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark this as solved.
